# How to populate my dictionary without a list?

Tags: python

I had an assignment to take a text file and find out who sent the most emails. I got the correct answer but the TA said I had to make a list because I had an uneeded for loop

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
email_dict = dict()
email_list = list()
for lines in handle:
    lines = lines.strip()
    if not lines.startswith('From '): continue
    from_lines = lines.split()
    email_list = [from_lines[1]]
    
    for email in email_list:
        email_dict[email] = email_dict.get(email,0) + 1
    
    
prolific_committer = None
bigcount = None
    
for email, count in email_dict.items():
    if prolific_committer is None or count > bigcount:
        prolific_committer = email
        bigcount = count
print(prolific_committer,bigcount)
```

How could I clean this up but more importantly why? I'm still learning and I'm understanding a lot of the concepts on their own. It's putting it all together is where I'm struggling.

Comment: Specification isn't clear. What's the input file and expected output supposed to be?

Comment: `email_list` has only one element, so this "loop" only iterates once, for that single element. Why write a loop?

Comment: Sorry the input file is a txt file with a bunch of random email stuff. I needed to extract all the emails sent to me and see who sent the most emails. The answer was "person's email  5"
That's where I ran into a problem. I couldn't get it to work without using a list. Before that it was just a bunch of strings and I didn't know how to get the strings into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
email_dict = dict()
email_list = list()
for lines in handle:
    lines = lines.strip()
    if not lines.startswith('From '): continue
    from_lines = lines.split()
    from_lines = from_lines[1]
    email_dict[from_lines] = email_dict.get(from_lines,0) + 1

prolific_committer = None
bigcount = None

for email, count in email_dict.items():
    if prolific_committer is None or count > bigcount:
        prolific_committer = email
        bigcount = count
print(prolific_committer,bigcount)
```